# Can't install PHP 7 support patch?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, php-7

I downloaded the official php7 support patch `PATCH-1.9.3.0_PHP7-2018-09-13-07-59-59.2_v2` from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).

I noticed that the file is downloaded without any extension, so I renamed it from `PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2` to `PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh`.

Then I executed the patch `sh PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh`.
But this is what I get:

```
diff: unrecognized option '--git'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh: line 2: index: command not found
PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh: line 3: ---: command not found
PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh: line 4: +++: command not found
PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.sh: line 5: `@@ -53,6 +53,9 @@ if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {'
```

Tested on a fresh Magento V1.9.3.10.
Do we have to patch the patch?

I installed another patch which also has the same `diff --git` command and that worked, but this patch wont work.

---

**UPDATE**

I tried it like this: `git apply PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2`

Im not sure if it worked because there was no output.

> Note: You can install these patches using either patch or git apply
>   . See the Instructions section of the Magento 1 Official
>   PHP 7.2 patches blog post for more information on both forms of
>   installation.

Info found [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).

Comment: please try: https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/

Comment: How to install it on Magento ver. 1.14.2.4 ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal 1.14 ? It is way too old, you first have to update it.

Comment: You mean updating magento version ?

Comment: Does patch fix compatibility issue on "lib" files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`patch -p1 < PATCH-1.9.3.0_PHP7-2018-09-13-07-59-59.2_v2`

Comment: According to Magento Team, this command is only for files with the extension "patch". But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To patch with GIT:

```
$ git apply --apply PATCH-1.9.3.0_PHP7-2018-09-13-07-59-59.2_v2
```